# Cannot get ACF from custom post type post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a custom post type called "members", which has an ACF field connected. I try to get the content of that field. But when I try, I only get the regular post object. Not the ACF fields connected.

Here is what i am trying, but only getting the post object.

`

```
$featuredmembers = get_field('featured_member');
global $post;

//$featuredmembers has a field named "featured". That's the field I want.


$posts = get_posts([
  'post_type' => 'members',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'posts_per_page' => -1,
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'orderby' => 'title'
]);


foreach ($featuredmembers as $post) {
  print_r($post['featured']->ID);
  echo get_field('featured');
}
```

`

Answer (score 1):

Try passing the `post id` in the get_field / the_field call within the foreach loop:

```
foreach ($featuredmembers as $post) {
    // the_field('featured', $post->ID);
    echo get_field('featured', $post->ID);
}
```

If it's a repeater field you can use:

```
foreach ($featuredmembers as $post) {
    the_repeater_field('featured', $post->ID);
}
```

Comment: Hi! I have actually tried that, since thats how i usually do it. But it wont work. I get nothing. Its a repeater field if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried the_repeater_field('featured', $post->ID); ?

Comment: Yes, same. No result.

Comment: Only thing that i get to work is to get the post. Like: `$post['featured']`. But i don not get its ACF fields.

Comment: Oh, where are you calling get_post? you might already be inside a wp_query. If so try call it after the query

Comment: Im calling it on line 10, looping it on line 97. See link: https://pastebin.com/7hNNZkkn

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be down the `foreach` loops using a variable of `$post`. This will override the main `$post` variable of the page, and any `get_field` function calls after the foreach loop will be looking at the wrong post.

Try renaming those variables to something other than `$post`